# Excel - Find first date occurrence for cell row that does not have a certain string

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup

For instance given the below table:

```
|A  |B          |C          |D          |E          |F         |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|1  |20.12.2017 |21.12.2017 |22.12.2017 |23.12.2017 |24.12.2017|
|2  |all        |all        |c          |d          |e         |
|3  |all        |b          |cc         |dd         |ee        |
```

How can I get for each row, the first date where the cell value is not `all`?

in the example, for first row will be: 22.12.2017 and second row: 21.12.2017.

I've tried with `Index` and `match`, and `lookup`. But I guess my problem is that I'd need some function

Comment: Where do you want to store the data? In Column G?

Comment: Once the columns have stopped containing "all" will they ever have "all" in them again? ie is all,all,c,d,all possible?

Answer (score 2):

If the phrase "all" is not repeated, you could use

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$F$3,0,COUNTIF(B2:F2,"all")+2)}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach; I had not thought of looking for a pattern.

Comment: and if column B is ccc and columns C-E are all and column F is eee??

Comment: I am making an assumption from the data that your example won't happen. If it does, then my solution won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try it as,

```
=INDEX(B$3:F$3, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:E)/(B4:F4<>"all"), 1))
```

Note¹ that you will retrieve raw numbers from your dates (e.g. 43091, 43090). Format the results as dates.

Note² that `COLUMN(A:E)` is offset one column to `B4:F4` but contains the same number of columns.

[image]

Comment: If you had bothered to read the notes I had typed out for you, you could have saved the time it took to ask an inane question and wait for an answer. Why would I type out a note explaining something that was mistyped to begin with?